# How to fix this error at start-up after an update of Unity?

Tags: unity

I receive this error after updating Unity to version 5.4.0p1:

```
Failed to query D3D11 context for ID3DUserDefinedAnnotation interface (hr = 0x80004002)
```

After some research, I did not find anything so I post it here. How it's fix?

Here it's my **Editor.Log** file:

```
LICENSE SYSTEM [2016820 9:45:38] Next license update check is after 2025-12-19T00:00:00
Built from '5.4/patch-release' branch; Version is '5.4.0p1 (e61faee5ea97) revision 15081390'; Using compiler version '160040219'
OS: 'Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (6.1.7601) 64bit' Language: 'en' Physical Memory: 3990 MB
BatchMode: 0, IsHumanControllingUs: 1, StartBugReporterOnCrash: 1, Is64bit: 1, IsPro: 1
Initialize mono
Mono path[0] = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/Mono/lib/mono/2.0'
Mono path[2] = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityScript'
Mono config path = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/Mono/etc'
Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,defer=y,address=0.0.0.0:56416
IsTimeToCheckForNewEditor: Update time 1471669718 current 1471666542
I:/Flappy Bird
Loading GUID <-> Path mappings...0.000173 seconds
Loading Asset Database...0.016619 seconds
Audio: FMOD Profiler initialized on port 54900
AssetDatabase consistency checks...0.030437 seconds
Initialize engine version: 5.4.0p1 (e61faee5ea97)
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 5.76 ms, found 1 plugins.
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.0]
    Renderer: Intel(R) HD Graphics (ID=0x152)
    Vendor:   Intel
    VRAM:     880 MB
Failed to query D3D11 context for ID3DUserDefinedAnnotation interface (hr = 0x80004002)
 (Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/d3d11/GfxDeviceD3D11.cpp Line: 871)
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEditor.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Unity.Locator.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\I18N.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\I18N.West.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Unity.DataContract.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Unity.IvyParser.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Xml.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Configuration.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PackageManager\Unity\PackageManager\5.4.0\Unity.PackageManager.dll (this message is harmless)
Initializing Unity.PackageManager (PackageManager) v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1
Setting Android v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer
Setting StandaloneWindows v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\windowsstandalonesupport
Setting Advertisements v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Advertisements
  UnityEngine.Advertisements.dll (Extension) GUID: 739bbd9f364b4268874f9fd86ab3beef
  Editor/UnityEditor.Advertisements.dll (Extension) GUID: 97decbdab0634cdd991f8d23ddf0dead
Setting EditorTestsRunner v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner
  Editor/nunit.framework.dll (Extension) GUID: 7cbab2be89b54486bbd23a6fe637d30e
  Editor/UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.dll (Extension) GUID: 3c0ad459c1534645b5d603b7cc258f97
Setting GUISystem v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem
  UnityEngine.UI.dll (Extension) GUID: f5f67c52d1564df4a8936ccd202a3bd8
  Editor/UnityEditor.UI.dll (Extension) GUID: 80a3616ca19596e4da0f10f14d241e9f
Setting UNetHLAPI v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking
  UnityEngine.Networking.dll (Extension) GUID: 870353891bb340e2b2a9c8707e7419ba
  Editor/UnityEditor.Networking.dll (Extension) GUID: 5f32cd94baa94578a686d4b9d6b660f7
Setting TreeEditor v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\TreeEditor
  Editor/UnityEditor.TreeEditor.dll (Extension) GUID: adebbd281f1a4ef3a30be7f21937e02f
Setting UnityAnalytics v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\UnityAnalytics
  UnityEngine.Analytics.dll (Extension) GUID: 852E56802EB941638ACBB491814497B0
Setting UnityPurchasing v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\UnityPurchasing
  UnityEngine.Purchasing.dll (Extension) GUID: 8E0CD8ED44D4412CBE0642067ABC9E44
Registering custom dll's ...
Register platform support module: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/UnityEditor.Android.Extensions.dll
Register platform support module: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\windowsstandalonesupport/UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.Extensions.dll
Registered in 0.073302 seconds.
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PackageManager\Unity\PackageManager\5.4.0\Unity.PackageManager.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PackageManager\Unity\PackageManager\5.4.0\Unity.PackageManager.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Advertisements\Editor\UnityEditor.Advertisements.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Advertisements\Editor\UnityEditor.Advertisements.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner\Editor\nunit.framework.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner\Editor\nunit.framework.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner\Editor\UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner\Editor\UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\Editor\UnityEditor.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\Editor\UnityEditor.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking\UnityEngine.Networking.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking\UnityEngine.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking\Editor\UnityEditor.Networking.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking\Editor\UnityEditor.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\TreeEditor\Editor\UnityEditor.TreeEditor.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\TreeEditor\Editor\UnityEditor.TreeEditor.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\JMO Assets\Editor\JMOAssets.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\JMO Assets\Editor\JMOAssets.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\I18N.MidEast.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\I18N.MidEast.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\I18N.Other.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\I18N.Other.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\I18N.Rare.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\I18N.Rare.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\System.Data.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\System.Data.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEditor.Graphs.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEditor.Graphs.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\UnityEditor.Android.Extensions.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\UnityEditor.Android.Extensions.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\windowsstandalonesupport\UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.Extensions.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\windowsstandalonesupport\UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.Extensions.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\nunit.core.interfaces.dll (this message is harmless)
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 0.36 ms, found 1 plugins.
Preloading 0 native plugins for Editor in 0.00 ms.
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Mono.Cecil.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Unity.SerializationLogic.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\UnityScript.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\ICSharpCode.NRefactory.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\nunit.core.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Transactions.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Mono.Data.Tds.dll (this message is harmless)
Mono: successfully reloaded assembly
- Completed reload, in  0.893 seconds
Registering platform support modules:
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Boo.Lang.Compiler.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Boo.Lang.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Boo.Lang.Parser.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\UnityScript.Lang.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Mono.Security.dll (this message is harmless)
Registered platform support modules in: 0.1201295s.
Native extension for WindowsStandalone target not found
Native extension for Android target not found
Downloading http://update.unity3d.com/5.4/ivy.xml to C:\Users\DARSHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\unity\85968888-3129-4314-87f1-74e4e633d110\ivy.xml
Reloading assemblies after successful script compilation.
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Shutting down Remote Indexer
Task failed: Downloader Task
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEditor.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Unity.Locator.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\I18N.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\I18N.West.dll (this message is harmless)
Registering custom dll's ...
Register platform support module: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/UnityEditor.Android.Extensions.dll
Register platform support module: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\windowsstandalonesupport/UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.Extensions.dll
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)
Registered in 0.099164 seconds.
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PackageManager\Unity\PackageManager\5.4.0\Unity.PackageManager.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PackageManager\Unity\PackageManager\5.4.0\Unity.PackageManager.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Advertisements\Editor\UnityEditor.Advertisements.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Advertisements\Editor\UnityEditor.Advertisements.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner\Editor\nunit.framework.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner\Editor\nunit.framework.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner\Editor\UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner\Editor\UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\Editor\UnityEditor.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\Editor\UnityEditor.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking\UnityEngine.Networking.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking\UnityEngine.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking\Editor\UnityEditor.Networking.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking\Editor\UnityEditor.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\TreeEditor\Editor\UnityEditor.TreeEditor.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\TreeEditor\Editor\UnityEditor.TreeEditor.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\JMO Assets\Editor\JMOAssets.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\JMO Assets\Editor\JMOAssets.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\I18N.MidEast.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\I18N.MidEast.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\I18N.Other.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\I18N.Other.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\I18N.Rare.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\I18N.Rare.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\System.Data.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading I:\Flappy Bird\Assets\Plugins\System.Data.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEditor.Graphs.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEditor.Graphs.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\UnityEditor.Android.Extensions.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\UnityEditor.Android.Extensions.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\windowsstandalonesupport\UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.Extensions.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\windowsstandalonesupport\UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.Extensions.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\nunit.core.interfaces.dll (this message is harmless)
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 0.42 ms, found 1 plugins.
Preloading 0 native plugins for Editor in 0.00 ms.
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Mono.Cecil.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Unity.SerializationLogic.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Unity.DataContract.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\UnityScript.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\ICSharpCode.NRefactory.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Unity.IvyParser.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\nunit.core.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Transactions.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Mono.Data.Tds.dll (this message is harmless)
Mono: successfully reloaded assembly
- Completed reload, in  0.741 seconds
Initializing Unity.PackageManager (PackageManager) v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1
Setting Android v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer
Setting StandaloneWindows v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\windowsstandalonesupport
Setting Advertisements v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Advertisements
  UnityEngine.Advertisements.dll (Extension) GUID: 739bbd9f364b4268874f9fd86ab3beef
  Editor/UnityEditor.Advertisements.dll (Extension) GUID: 97decbdab0634cdd991f8d23ddf0dead
Setting EditorTestsRunner v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner
  Editor/nunit.framework.dll (Extension) GUID: 7cbab2be89b54486bbd23a6fe637d30e
  Editor/UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.dll (Extension) GUID: 3c0ad459c1534645b5d603b7cc258f97
Setting GUISystem v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem
  UnityEngine.UI.dll (Extension) GUID: f5f67c52d1564df4a8936ccd202a3bd8
  Editor/UnityEditor.UI.dll (Extension) GUID: 80a3616ca19596e4da0f10f14d241e9f
Setting UNetHLAPI v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking
  UnityEngine.Networking.dll (Extension) GUID: 870353891bb340e2b2a9c8707e7419ba
  Editor/UnityEditor.Networking.dll (Extension) GUID: 5f32cd94baa94578a686d4b9d6b660f7
Setting TreeEditor v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\TreeEditor
  Editor/UnityEditor.TreeEditor.dll (Extension) GUID: adebbd281f1a4ef3a30be7f21937e02f
Setting UnityAnalytics v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\UnityAnalytics
  UnityEngine.Analytics.dll (Extension) GUID: 852E56802EB941638ACBB491814497B0
Setting UnityPurchasing v5.4.0 for Unity v5.4.0p1 to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\UnityPurchasing
  UnityEngine.Purchasing.dll (Extension) GUID: 8E0CD8ED44D4412CBE0642067ABC9E44
Registering platform support modules:
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Boo.Lang.Compiler.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Boo.Lang.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Boo.Lang.Parser.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\UnityScript.Lang.dll (this message is harmless)
Registered platform support modules in: 0.0633843s.
Native extension for WindowsStandalone target not found
Native extension for Android target not found
Validating Project structure ... 0.028280 seconds.
Refresh: detecting if any assets need to be imported or removed ... Refresh: elapses 0.028525 seconds (Nothing changed)
Warming cache for 1967 main assets: 0.015007 seconds elapsed
Initializing Unity extensions:
 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/UnityAnalytics/UnityEngine.Analytics.dll' 
 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/GUISystem/UnityEngine.UI.dll' 
 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/Networking/Editor/UnityEditor.Networking.dll' 
 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/TreeEditor/Editor/UnityEditor.TreeEditor.dll' 
 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/EditorTestsRunner/Editor/UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.dll' 
 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/Networking/UnityEngine.Networking.dll' 
 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/Advertisements/Editor/UnityEditor.Advertisements.dll' 
 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/GUISystem/Editor/UnityEditor.UI.dll' 
 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/UnityPurchasing/UnityEngine.Purchasing.dll' 
 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/EditorTestsRunner/Editor/nunit.framework.dll' 
 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/Advertisements/UnityEngine.Advertisements.dll' 
Load scene 'Assets/Scenes/Menu.unity' time: 0.014026 ms 
Unloading 189 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
System memory in use before: 35.8 MB.
System memory in use after: 35.8 MB.
Unloading 9 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 1086.
Total: 5.100740 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.442337 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.110156 ms MarkObjects: 4.509246 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.036604 ms)
<RI> Initializing input.
XInput1_3.dll not found. Trying XInput9_1_0.dll instead...
<RI> Input initialized.
Issue TrimJob to reduce GI Cache size to maximum 10GB at: 'C:/Users/Darshan Soni/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/Caches/GiCache'
Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
  Thread -> id: 7c8 -> priority: 1 
Launched and connected shader compiler UnityShaderCompiler.exe after 0.62 seconds
TrimDiskCacheJob: Current cache size 69mb
Refresh: detecting if any assets need to be imported or removed ... Refresh: elapses 0.028466 seconds (Nothing changed)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens on machines that have Windows 7 without any service packs installed. While this error is harmless, you can work around it by updating Windows.